# Setting a database value to context variable in talend

Tags: talend

I have a job that flows like this.

```
  tAccessDatabse_1 ---> tFileOutputXML_1.
```

Now, my database has a schema, with usename and userid. My task to create/send data from the database to xml file, file name with username i.e, one file has to create for every user with his/her name.

I tried like creating a conetxt varible but how can i set username to that context variable from the database ??

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Did u mean you need to set a context variable from the username you used to connect to database OR you need to create context variables from a main flow coming from a db table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select distinct username from table.
2. Use tFlowToIterate to iterate on each of the usernames. (connect table component to this component using main link)
3. Use Iterate link to connect to tJava component.
4. Assign the username to context variable using tjava component. For eg. if output row from the table component is row1, then `context.username=row1.username`.
5. Connect tJava to a table component using `'OnComponentOk'` to Select data from table based on the where condition: `username='"+context variable+"'`
6. Write data into file. Give filename as `"<path>\"+context.username`.

Answer (score 1):

`tYOURDBInput -> [row1] -> tFlowToItterate -> [itterate] -> tJava -> "globalMap.put("DESC", (String)row1.column);"`

If you have just the one line then pick it up elsewhere via

`(String) globalMap.get("DESC")`

I used this setup to retrieve passwords to foreign systems stored in a table which are to be refreshed regurarily. This prevents code rebuilds everytime the password changes. Do protect your table naturally.