# Talend how to use an Oracle database created sequence

Tags: oracle, talend

I've created a sequence object in Oracle DB and I need to assign it to a context variable in Talend and so that I can increment the value from Talend. 
How can I do that? What component should I use and how can I assign the value to the variable? I couldn't find any guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a database value to context variable in talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468536/setting-a-database-value-to-context-variable-in-talend)

Comment: @hotfix I do not have a table on my DB where I get the sequence, I have a "sequence object" so I cannot iterate on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said that your `Sequence` is already created, assuming you (your schema) will be having `SELECT` privilege on the `Sequence`.

In that case you could simply say (to generate the next sequence number) -

`SELECT <yoursequencename>.NEXTVAL FROM dual;`

Put this query in your `tOracleInput` and connect a row to say `tJavaRow`. In `tJavaRow` you would have to read the input row value and assign it to your already created context variable, something like this -

```
context.CurrentDate = input_row.CurrentDate;
System.out.println(context.CurrentDate);
```